# Get the values from dynamic NumericUpDown in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created dynamic NumericUpDown. I want to save the values that the user enters. How can i do that. After I am saving the values I want to  do  some time manipulation with them.  Knowing I do not know the number of NumericUpDown the user wants each time?

```
// To set up the location for the NumericUpDown
int xCoor;
int yCoor;

Random coor = new Random();

// Button to create the NumericUpDown

private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    /// I am assuming that the user choice is 8
    int value = 8;

    //this calls the method which is going to create NumericUpDown
    this.AddNewNumrical(value);

}

//Method to Create NumericUpDown
private void AddNewNumrical(int numiraclNew)
{

    for (int x = 0; x < numiraclNew; x++)
    {

        for (int y = 0; y < 1; y++)
        {

            NumericUpDown numiNumber = new NumericUpDown();
            xCoor = coor.Next(0, 700);
            yCoor = coor.Next(0, 710);
            numiNumber.Location = new Point(xCoor, yCoor);


            numiNumber.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 15);
            numiNumber.Maximum = 1000;
            numiNumber.Minimum = 1;
            this.pnlNodes.Controls.Add(numiNumber);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Save the values where?  What kind of "time manipulation"?

Comment: after I save the values I want to make my program run after summing the values from the ramdom NumericUpDown.

Comment: I am lost I want to use Array or array list or queu

Comment: First of all, your inner `for` loop is unnecessary. Its only running the loop one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store your new `NumericUpDown` control in another list! You could also search the `Controls` collection for `NumericUpDown` controls but you might pick up some stuff you don't want:

```
List<NumericUpDown> numberControls = new List<NumericUpDown>();

//Method to Create NumericUpDown
private void AddNewNumrical(int numiraclNew)
{

    for (int x = 0; x < numiraclNew; x++)
    {
        NumericUpDown numiNumber = new NumericUpDown();
        xCoor = coor.Next(0, 700);
        yCoor = coor.Next(0, 710);
        numiNumber.Location = new Point(xCoor, yCoor);

        numiNumber.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 15);
        numiNumber.Maximum = 1000;
        numiNumber.Minimum = 1;
        numberControls.Add(numiNumber); //Save the control off for later
        this.pnlNodes.Controls.Add(numiNumber);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it later to do whatever you want:

```
private void Foo()
{
    foreach (NumericUpDown userSelection in numberControls)
    {
         //Do whatever with userSelection.Value
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the code you  gave me but it does not showing any  information